# Where is CompostionContainer in MEF 2?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, mef

Simple question: Where is CompostionContainer in MEF 2? (http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.composition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new System.Composition.Hosting.ContainerConfiguration().CreateContainer()
```